# Foreign keys in tables

Tags: foreign-keys, db2

when we create a foreign key in a table does it always become a duplicate index?

Comment: Please state the database system you are using and explain what you mean by "duplicate index". Also, you should accept more answers if you wish people to put effort into your questions.

Comment: Sorry about that - the question was meant to be for a general RDBMS. Specifically i am using DB2 z/OS V9.1. By duplicate index i mean - duplicate index at the table level.

Comment: It's dependent on the specific database system - some might automatically create an index, others will not. This **cannot** be answered for all products in general.

Answer (score 0):

In DB2 for z/OS, if you create a table with a foreign key, you do not have to define an index on its underlying column.

An index will not be defined automatically when you create the table.  If you want one, you can create one separately (via a `CREATE INDEX` statement).  I think it is common to define an index that includes the foreign key column(s), but it is not a requirement.  It all depends on how your application accesses the data.

For an overview on DB2 keys, check this out:  http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/basics/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2z.doc.intro/db2z_keys.html.